# MySQL count include to jSon object

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I made a php/ajax/mysql/json script for my site, to show all the tags.

If I GET the page id it will show me all the tags of that page.
But! In my main page i'd like to show all tags, from all pages WITH a counter.

For example if I tagged 4 pages with

```
"**ilovestackoverflow**"
```

i'd like to see in my main page

```
"**ilovestackoverflow (4)**"
```

I know I can count the lines with mysql COUNT() but unfortunatlety I can't use it in this case, however I tried much way :(

(function sqlnez($value) is my stripslashes script)

the php:

```
$server = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
$connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);
//if got pageID
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE id=".sqlnez($_GET['id'])."");
  $json = "({ tags:["; 
  for ($x = 0, $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query); $x < $numrows; $x++) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $json .= "{tag:'" . $row["tag"] . "'}";
      if ($x < mysql_num_rows($query) -1)  
        $json .= ",";  
      else
        $json .= "]})";
    }
}
//this is the part what needs help
//if got nothing
else { 
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags GROUP BY tag");
  $json = "({ tags:["; 
  for ($x = 0, $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query); $x < $numrows; $x++) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $json .= "{tag:'" . $row["tag"] . "',counter:'" . I WANT THE COUNTER HERE . "'}";
    if ($x < mysql_num_rows($query) -1)  
      $json .= ",";  
    else
      $json .= "]})";
  }
}

$response = $_GET["callback"] . $json;
echo utf8_encode($response);
mysql_close($server);
```

Thanks for your help and time :)

Comment: In the future, you should try to indent your code. It's better for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your sql request should be `SELECT tag, COUNT (*) as count FROM tags GROUP BY tag` then replace `I WANT THE COUNTER HERE` with `$row['count']`

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/.../tagcloud.php on line 39

That is the $query = mysql_query("SELECT tag, COUNT (*) as count FROM tags GROUP BY tag"); line.

:(

Comment: @Zoltan Repas You must always check the return value of mysql_query(): it can return a result set... or not. See the manual for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing json by hand (this is an extremely bad idea, no matter what) you should use [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.phphttp://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)